# Linux and reading and writing a general purpose 32 bit register

Tags: linux-device-driver

I am using embedded Linux for the NIOS II processor and device tree. The GPIO functionality provides the ability to read and or write a single bit at a time. I have some firmware and PIOS that I want to read or write atomically by setting or reading all 32 bits at one time. It seems like there would be a generic device driver that if the device tree was given the proper compatibility a driver would exist that would allow opening the device and then reading and writing the device. I have searched for this functionality and do not find a driver. One existing in a branch but was removed by Linus.

My question is what is the Linux device tree way to read and write a device that is a general purpose 32 bit register/pio?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is SCULL

[Character Device Drivers](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch03.pdf)

You will have to write a character device driver with file operations to open and close a device. Read, write, ioctl, and copy the contents of device.

```
static struct file_operations query_fops =
{
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = my_open,
    .release = my_close,
    .ioctl = my_ioctl
};
```

Map the address using iomem and directly read and write to that address using rawread and rawwrite. Create and register a device as follows and then it can be accessed from userspace:

```
register_chrdev (0, DEVICE_NAME, & query_fops);

device_create (dev_class, NULL, MKDEV (dev_major, 0), NULL, DEVICE_NAME);
```

and then access it from userspace as follows:

```
 fd = open("/dev/mydevice", O_RDWR);
```

and then you can play with GPIO from userspace using ioctl's:

```
ioctl(fd, SET_STATE);
```